# Spatie Media Library Performing conversions

Tags: laravel, image-processing

I have been using spatie media library for over a year and a half and over the last month have encountered the folloing error:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeExceptionSpatie\MediaLibrary\Jobs\PerformConversions
The provided cwd "" does not exist.

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException · The provided cwd "" does not exist.
vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:344 Symfony\Component\Process\Process::start 
        }
        if (!is_dir($this->cwd)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('The provided cwd "%s" does not exist.', $this->cwd));
        }
        $this->process = @proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $envPairs, $this->options);
```

Not sure why all of a sudden it will start throwing this error. ANy help will be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks
Danny

Comment: Which code are you using that triggers this error?

Comment: Have you checked your config? `config/media-library.php`

Comment: Yinci what am I lookig for in the config file?